# x:Bind works but Binding doesn't (opposite to most Q&A found)

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

Most of the Q&A I found on StackOverflow is how Binding work but `x:Bind` doesn't which usually solved by `Bindings.Update()`. However, my issue is, inside a `GridView`, `ItemSource="{x:Bind _myList}"` works but `ItemSource="{Binding _myList}"` doesn't.

Why? And how do I make Binding work? (instead of `x:Bind`)

Here's a few code thingies:

Class:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    public string prop1 {get; set;}
    public string prop2 {get; set;} 
}

public class MyList : List<MyClass>
{ 
    public void Populate()
    // Add items 
}
```

Code Behind

```
public MyList _myList = new MyList();
_myList.Populate();
DataContext = this;
Bindings.Update();
```

XAML (doesn't work here but works if ItemSource: changed into `x:Bind _myList`)

```
<GridView ItemSource="{Binding _myList}">
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop1}"/> <TextBlock Text="{Binding prop2}/>
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that your `_myList` is field, not property. So, change to

```
public MyList _myList { get; set; } = new MyList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. And I never expected asking on StackOverflow is so easy. I'm a very beginner into programming and don't understand the difference between field and property and why x:Bind works on a field and Binding doesn't, but I'm on my way looking up to learn more.